# inbox for normal push notifications

Tags: android, push-notification, urbanairship.com, inbox

I'm using Urban Airship to handle the push notifications (for Android) and I know they have inbox functionality but it works only for rich push notifications. I'm trying to get it work for all the notifications (so that all the notifications received by the phone to be in the inbox). But I couldn't get it to work because I figured the Rich Push notifications inbox has its own library. But if the Urban Airship has its notification history stored in their webpage, so it is also possible to get the notification history in the inbox (which I don't know how). I've also searched but haven't been able to find anything about it. Anyone can help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't believe UA API has access to the message "history" at this time. It's part of their proprietary messaging tool.

I think the only way to accomplish a poor push inbox would be to implement your own push portal, that basically throws requests to the UA API.